# Comparitive degree as a Modifier!

Tags: adjectives, modifiers, comparative-degree

> The incident gave hardly an impact  upon his vastly ***greater***
>   preoccupations

Is comparative used as a modifier? If so, then how it could be used without any comparison shown in the sentence?

Comment: Please edit the formation and include the whole context if you please.

Comment: There's an implied comparison, that it's greater than something else, but without more context it's impossible to say what the something else is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a native speaker and an English teacher.  Since I don't know the context or the intended use of the sentence, it's a little hard to answer.

If you want to restate it without the comparative, you could say:

- The incident hardly made an impact on his other preoccupations.
- The incident hardly made an impact on his great preoccupations.

Comment: I am not the original asker, but may I ask you a question? Can I alter the original sentence ***The incident gave hardly an impact upon his vastly greater preoccupations*** into ***The incident hardly gave an impact upon his vastly greater preoccupations*** with the change of the position of **hardly**? The latter sentence sounds more right to me, though I am a foreigner learning English. If you answer this with a comment, I would be greatly grateful for that. Thank you.